# How to show results to users that can be editable?

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java and I need your opinion on the best way to show results of a database to the users of my program.

The data which I provide will be in standard format, after querying in MySql and there is no need to change this query. So there is no need to change the way they look, but I would like to add some functionality.

To be more specific I would like them to be able to click on the path of files and open them with the default program of their operating system and to gather some boolean data from one column of this table.

Comment: _The data which I provide will be in standard format_ Which standard? And how does editable come into play in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class has a method that allows you to open a file in a text editor.

Comment: If for example the document has .doc extension, will this method open the Office word?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  What did you gather from reading the docs.?  Do you expect to be spoon-fed?

Comment: I didnt try anything till now. I just need to gather some ideas on how to implement this task in a better way.

Comment: @Vagelism - details like that are platform specific.  They only way to be sure is to actually try it.  (And no, I wouldn't expect Java on Linux to run Microsoft Word for a ".doc" file.  It might run OpenOffice or LibreOffice though ...)